# Cordova Geolocation (Watch position): activate some .js when Device is on a particular area

Tags: javascript, cordova

I've edited the example for Geolocation in Cordova to do something (in this case an alert) if the user is up a certain latitude there is an alert, if not another alert. But it doesn't work. Can someone Help me?

```
 // Wait for device API libraries to load
 //
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 var watchID = null;

 // device APIs are available
 //
 function onDeviceReady() {
   // Throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds
   var options = {
     maximumAge: 15000,
     timeout: 30000,
     enableHighAccuracy: true
   };
   watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
 }

 // onSuccess Geolocation
 //
 function onSuccess(position) {
   var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
   element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
     'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' +
     '<hr />' + element.innerHTML;
 }

 if (position.coords.latitude > 44.48) {
   alert("Hi Wayne");
 } else if {
   alert("Hi Bill");
 }

 // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
 //
 function onError(error) {
   alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
     'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
 }
```

Comment: Can you specify in more detail what the expected result is?

Comment: Sure! sorry for my bad english!  If the user is somewhere between a determinate latitude and longitude i will load a .Js.. If not nothing happens.. In this example i use alert to demonstrate that it doesn't work. Thanks in advice!